# Disable horizontal scrolling on mobile doesn´t work

Tags: html, css

I am still a rookie in programming, but I want to know how I can disable horizontal scrolling on mobile devices. As you can see on my webpage  [here](http://redpandaskateboards.de/)  the picture on the top is bigger than the device-width. I tried nearly all I could find in this forum, but nothing really helped.

I put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">` into the head,

tried `body{overflow-x:hidden}` in various combinations but nothing worked :/

Comment: You're misunderstanding `overflow`: [overflow | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)

Comment: On my machine everything works just fine. Tried resized and everything and didn't get any horizontal scroll bar!

Answer (score 1):

Your website works on mobile Firefox and Chrome, but not on the Android standard browser. Maybe this browser needs `user-scalable=no`.

Just add it to your meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

This also works for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```